# Can't build because of this errors using intellij idea

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 8 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-2.1.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
^
symbol:   variable S
location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-2.1.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());
^
symbol:   method isMock()
location: variable location of type Location
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you need to update the build.gradle to:

...
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
...

I had the same issue.  Check the Changelog for the geolocator package here.

- Updated dependency on geolocator_android to version 2.0.0
- Make sure the Android example App compiles against Android SDK 31.

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator/changelog